# Error on GetSelectNamesDialog in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

So i have been struggling with this issue for about a week now. The below code is the opening portion of a project I'm working on.

The goal here is to open up the `address-book` pop-up for the Global Address List in outlook. I gathered most of this code from another question or two here on stacked overflow. The issue is, when I get to the final line

```
Set Dialog = outlookApp.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
```

I get a "Run-time error '287': Application-defined or object-defined error"
Yes, Outlook 16.0 reference library is checked off.
I was curious about object security blocking.
I recently updated to GetGlobalAddressList to fix a similair issue.

```
Sub AddTestConductor() 'inserts information for a new TC from GAL

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Dialog As Outlook.SelectNamesDialog
Dim GAL As Outlook.AddressList
Dim TCEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim User As Outlook.ExchangeUser

Dim Alias As String
Dim FirstName As String
Dim LastName As String
Dim Email As String
Dim where As String


Set OutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 'grabs outlook for use
Set OutlookNameSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
OutlookNameSpace.Logon , , True, False
Set GAL = OutlookApp.Session.GetGlobalAddressList
Set Dialog = OutlookApp.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog

With Dialog
    .AllowMultipleSelection = False
    .InitialAddressList = GAL
    .ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = True
    If .Display Then
        Alias = Dialog.Recipients.Item(1).Name
        Set TCEntry = GAL.AddressEntries(Alias)
        Set User = TCEntry.GetExchangeUser

        If Not User Is Nothing Then  'populate variable for name and e-mail0
            FirstName = User.FirstName
            LastName = User.LastName
            Email = User.PrimarySmtAddress
        End If
    End If
End With

Set OutlookApp = Nothing           'Empty objects for next use
Set Dialog = Nothing
Set GAL = Nothing
Set TCEntry = Nothing
Set User = Nothing
```

In addition to the above, I would like to specify a sub folder withing th GAL, to wean the list down.

Info grabbed from the GAL with be inserted into a spreadsheet, then I will need to create links to calendar dates from their information as well. I haven't gotten that far yet.

I'm currently just trying to gather info about a user as baby step number one.

Comment: Try with NewSession as true? `OutlookNameSpace.Logon , , True, True`. Step through the code and pause at that line. Are you able to successfuly logon? And then continue debugging. What happens?

Comment: One more thing. Try latebinding instead of Early Binding and check

Comment: Is Outlook running? what version of office are you using?

Comment: Alright, One question at a time. Yes, outlook is running and open when attempting to open the Select names Dialog. As far as binding, I have developed the same issue with both late and early binding. I did read online about outlook object security that may block use of certain methods. Could that be what is happening. I will test the logon script and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Outlook and Excel 2016 are being used. And it is probably also important to note that I am on a government network. Could be important

Comment: I attempted the logon method, with no change. But, I will also mention, i also cannot tell if it has logged in or not. How would I test this? Outlook is already open and logged into when I run this code. Do I even need the logon script?